# Extrude a cylinder from the side of another cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I'm trying to extrude a cylinder from the side of another cylinder. Imagine a 3D stick figure. I want to extrude the "arms" of the stick figure, but they need to also be cylinders. When I extrude, the sides of the extrusion are flat, like this:

[image]

I'm new to Blender, so there may be a simple solution... I just haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks for any help!

Comment: does it come from the top of your stick or anywhere in the middle?

Comment: I'm having it stick out the middle of the cylinder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way is to use the *Knife Project* tool:

- Duplicate the top of your cylinder, rotate the circle and make it another object.
- Go in front view, select the circle, then the cylinder, and go in *Edit* mode.
- Press the *Knife Project* button on the Tools panel (on your left, activated with <kbd>T</kbd>).
- Now you have a circle marked on your cylinder. You can get rid of you circle object.
- Delete the faces of this circle.
- Extrude the edges.
- Flatten on the Y axis with a <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.
- Fill the hole with <kbd>F</kbd>.
- As it's better to only have quads, give an edge loop around the cylinder, use the knife: <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut perpendicularly.
- You have what you need (I guess).

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you make a Minecraft model, then select the edges, where the limbs connects to the torso, increase the mean crease and add a subdivision surface modifier.[image]